# Visual Studio 2019 is not working correctly for Windows Forms Projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

We are worming on Windows forms project which uses [CAB Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_UI_Application_Block) and [Infragistics Ultra Win Controls](https://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms) .
We have a common project which is being used in almost every project and have custom controls (Wrapper over infragistics controls).

Till .Net framework 4.7 and Visual Studio 2017 everything was working fine but when we have upgraded our solution to .net framework 4.8 and visual studio to 2019 (16.6.4 current version) along with infragistics control latest version, it starts creating issues for us. Below things stopped working at all.

1. Edit & Continue (Tried all possible combinations from stackoverflow and google responses)
2. IntelliSense (works on few projects)
3. References Navigation (works in few files)

After upgrade, we have removed all obj and bin folders, deleted .vs folder and rebuild solution. Also refreshed each project one by one.

I can rebuild, run and debug the application but can not edit code during debugging.

If anyone have any solution, then it will be a great help. We are feeling like coding in NotePad due to above issues.

Here is my Visual Studio Configuration
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the Windows Form project which uses CAB architecture and custom controls.

After reporting it to microsoft they have pushed some updated in the newest version and now everything is working fine.